# How to open and close tool strip menu drop down on alternative click c#

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

Here is a menu item **View** which has to be opened only on click and also closing of drop down has to occur only on click on the tool strip menu.

Comment: Your answer doesn't match the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

There are no methods to check if a drop down is opened on not except the DropDownOpened event. Which would have helped to toggle the opening and closing of Drop down. Moreover we don't have any methods to open Drop Down of Tool strip menu manually, which is definitely fixed with automation.

So to achieve this easily, we can use a bool variable as a reference of Drop Down open condition and click event can have the main logic.

During the Initialization of Code we have to take care of two things

```
_isViewMenuDropDownOpened = false;
tsmi_ViewMenu.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
```

Then in the Click event we can have something like

```
private void tsmi_ViewMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (_isViewMenuDropDownOpened)
     {
       tsmi_ViewMenu.DropDown.Close();
       tsmi_ViewMenu.Text = "View ▲";
       _isViewMenuDropDownOpened = false;
     }
     else
     {
         tsmi_ViewMenu.Text = "View ▼";
         _isViewMenuDropDownOpened = true;
     }
}
```

That does the job

[image]

Open

[image]

Close

Comment: That was "fast" ;)

Comment: @CaiusJard OP added a question with an answer, it wasn't 'fast' I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh, I know... It was a slightly tongue in cheek; clearly a large amount of prep had gone into the question and the answer, then a paste q/post/answer/paste/post all in the same minute.. Though I'm kinda not sure why; gaming the system? I've answered my own questions before but only after asking then slogging away for days...

Comment: @CaiusJard there is an option i think to post both question and answer together

Comment: Stackipedia? Swikioverflow? :)